# Problem involving summation and binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I have been fighting with this but I'm really not getting anywhere.
$$\sum_{0\leq2k\leq n}\binom{n}{2k}2^k\equiv0\pmod 3$$ 
$$iff$$
$$n\equiv2\pmod 4$$
Hint: Consider
$$\frac{1}{2}((1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n)$$
Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the last expression with the binomial theorem you will see that it matches with the first one. The next step is to prove that the sequence defined by
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{2}\left((1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n\right)$$
satisfies the recurrence relation:

$$ a_{n+2} = 2 a_{n+1} + a_{n},\quad a_0 = 1,a_1=1 $$
hence the sequence $\!\!\pmod{3}$ is $\overline{1,1,0,1,2,2,0,2}$ and the zeroes occur iff $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Ok, so I have expanded the last expression and found that it's equal to the first. But I unfortunately don't get how to reach the recurrence relation. How do you do that in a systematic way?

Comment: Try to reverse things. If you have a recurrence relation like: $$A_{n+2} = a A_{n+1} + b A_{n}$$ then the general term is given by: $$A_n = c \sigma^n + d \bar{\sigma}^n$$ where $c,d$ are suitable constants and $\sigma,\bar{\sigma}$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $x^2-ax-b$. Vieta's theorem just gives $$\sigma+\bar{\sigma}=a,\sigma\bar{\sigma}=-b.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another trick to show this is the following:

$2^k = (-1)^k$ mod $3$.

So you are left with the alternating sum $n \choose 0$- $n \choose2$+ $n \choose 4$-... (mod $3$).

You can now easily see that if $n = 2$ (mod $4$ )then this sum is zero.